# How to ssh into another laptop on same public WIFI?

Tags: ssh, wifi, rsync

I'm trying to ssh into another laptop on on a public WIFI.  I get the message:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.1.20.213.  No route to host
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Network configuration please. Is your client and the server even on the same subnet?

Comment: Most public WiFi hotspots forbid connections between peers due to security issues.

Comment: Yes both laptops are on a public WIFI ... Like if you go to Starbucks and connect two laptops to WIFI ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the public wifi isolates connections (like it appears to be in your case) you can use a third party to connect to the other device.

- Either set up your own virtual server and create a VPN with Wireguard (have the laptop connect with the `PersistentKeepalive` option and make the server forwards the traffic)
- or use a paid service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/product) (I have never used them so YMMV).